# Lagom service test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, microservices, lagom

Our team start to use the lagom framework to create microservice. I try to create the service test (the service consume the relational database). I did read the document about the service testing https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.5.x/java/Test.html. However there is no database involved.

As my understanding, the ServiceTest utilities start a fake service and run your service in it. However how to start a the database server? use withJdbc() to setup? Also need to create the test data? I'm new to lagom, can anyone provide some sample java service test code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ServiceTest provides a fake server to up your database. "withJdbc" is used for relational databases while "withCassandra" is used for Cassandra database.
Lagom provides embedded Cassandra database where you can flush your testing data or you can use in memory H2 database for testing purpose.